# OS vs "Code Base" on SSD vs HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance

I have a HDD and also a SSD in my Windows computer. Also I have a C++ code base that spend nearly one hour to compile. I'm keeping the code base in my HDD and installed the OS in SSD.
 But I have seen some people use a secondary SSD for the same code base, and they can compile it withing 10 min. 
But in my case, I don't have a secondary SSD. So my plan is, move OS to HDD and move code-base to SSD.

Will it impact OS performance in considerable way? Will it help to build the code base faster considering overall change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from SSD to HDD will most likely reduce your OS speed.

There is already an answer to this question, that You can find in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199356/speed-up-compile-time-with-ssd

Answer (score 0):

It will reduce your OS speed, and maybe increase your build speed. I imagine there is a lot of reading with lots of files during the build process, and writing new files. SSDs have less latency when starting a read, and are more parallel because all parts of the storage can be accessed at once - these are both good for reading lots of files. They also have higher throughput.

However, [this test from Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/03/27.html) resulted in compile time not improving. The bottom line is that the CPU is what really matters. It might improve, but a better CPU would really help, and maybe faster/more memory.

[Here's another](http://blog.kdgregory.com/2014/06/is-that-ssd-really-helping-your-build.html) more recent test I found.